# Error Type '{ id: number; name: string; time: string; }[]'

Tags: typescript

Buenas estoy practicando con typescript y he querido hacer una inyección con un array para que se mostrase por consola, el caso es que no para de salirme este error indicándome que los datos no son adecuados y no entiendo bien el porque. Aquí adjunto las fotos del código que tiene relaciona con el problema ya que son diferentes archivos y no encuentro otra forma de poder mostrarlo sin imágenes
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui adjunto el codigo de la imagen

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';
import { CourseService } from '../course.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-from-first',
  templateUrl: './from-first.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./from-first.component.css']
})
export class FromFirstComponent implements OnInit{

  status = "Formulario no ha sido enviado";
  defaultName = "";
  user = "";
  displayPassword = false;
  lightStatus = "YELLOW";
  names = ['Jacinto','Antonio','Maria','Juan']

  //@Input() parentDataToChild: any
  @Input('parentDataToChild') messageFromParent: any

  @Output()childEvent = new EventEmitter();


  courses = []


    constructor(private courseService: CourseService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
       this.courses= this.courseService.getCourses() 
       console.log(this.courses);
    }

    onSendForm(email : any){
      console.log(email)
      this.status = "El formulario ha sido enviado";
    }

    onDefaultForm(){
      this.defaultName = "Jacinto";
    }

    onSendEvent(){
      this.childEvent.emit('Enviando evento desde hijo hasta padre');
    }

}
```

Y imagen y le codigo del inyector
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CourseService {

  constructor() { }
  getCourses(){
    return[
      {'id':1, 'name':'MEAN', 'time':'10'},
      {'id':2, 'name':'Angular', 'time':'16'},
      {'id':3, 'name':'Java', 'time':'9'},
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Si quieres adjunta una captura del árbol de archivos pero copia el código como texto

Comment: @Mateo He añadido mas información mira ahora.